# How to search in unconnected external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, search

I have three harddisks.
1. Laptop harddisk ( 720gb )
2. Two External harddisk ( 1TB each )

These two external hard disk mainly contain movies, songs, games etc. Now, the point is I can't remember which movie is in which external hdd. For that I have to connect the hdd on by one and search.  ( Infact I know there exists duplicate copies of same files as well ).

Is there any software which can index the data in external hdd and later on it can use this data to search? That way I will be able to search in all my hdd without connecting these.

*I am using Windows 7.*

Answer (score 1):

Its not perfect, but you could connect the exernal drive and use the **Tree** command to index it.

Run CMD as Administrator and type

Tree F:\ /f /a >C:\HDDNameHere.txt

Where F:\ is the drive you want to index, and C:\HDDNameHere.txt is the drive (C:) and filename of the text file

Make the text file name something meaningful so you can match it to the external drive.

Comment: and after that search in this file instead of using windows search. right?

Comment: That's the Idea, you could also use >> rather than > when outputting the second file to append the first one, giving you one place to search.

Comment: I tried what you said sir, but again this is not user friendly. Thanks anyways. I will create one software for it.

Comment: I use `tree /F /A > "Tree %date:/=-%.txt"` (creates a file like "Tree Sun 05-11-2014.txt") in the root directory of the external drive and then copy that file to dropbox for a backup.